# How to multiple join with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Let's say I have three tables in a straight OneToMany relationships.

```
grandparent TABLE
-----------------
id             PK AI

parent      TABLE
-----------------
id             PK AI
grandparent_id FK ManyToOne NOT NULL

child       TABLE
-----------------
id             PK AI
parent_id      FK ManyToOne NOT NULL
```

When I want to select parents and grandparents while selecting children, which of following two queries right?

```
SELECT * FROM child AS c
    INNER JOIN (parent AS p INNER JOIN grandparent AS g ON p.grandparent_id = g.id)
    ON c.parent_id = p.id

SELECT * FROM child AS c
    INNER JOIN parent AS p ON c.parent_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN grandparent AS g ON p.grandparent_id = g.id
```

Are they same both internally and outernally?

Comment: Go with the second one. It's much clearer to read and understand.

Comment: What is your desired output?  Do you want to see all three generations in a single record, or something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes it is. I want both ancestors while selecting children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would left join, twice, from grandparents to parents and then to children.  The motivation behind this is that not all ancestors may have had children, yet you might want to still include them in your report.

```
SELECT
    t1.ID AS grandparent_id
    CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NOT NULL
         THEN CAST(t2.ID AS VARCHAR) ELSE 'NA' END AS parent_id,
    CASE WHEN t3.ID IS NOT NULL
         THEN CAST(t3.ID AS VARCHAR) ELSE 'NA' END AS child_id
FROM grandparent t1
LEFT JOIN parent t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.grandparent_id
LEFT JOIN child t3
    ON t2.ID = t3.parent_id
ORDER BY
    t1.ID, t2.ID, t3.ID;
```